# TeX question: ! File ended while scanning use of \multicolumn

Tags: multicolumn

Code for the table:

```
    {
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{c}}
\toprule
                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}         \\
\midrule
tt\_tn           &   -0.043         &   -0.044         &   -0.042         &                  \\
                &  [0.051]         &  [0.046]         &  [0.049]         &                  \\
\addlinespace
tt\_ntn          &   -0.015         &   -0.016         &   -0.010         &                  \\
                &  [0.051]         &  [0.048]         &  [0.050]         &                  \\
\addlinespace
sp              &    0.002         &                  &                  &                  \\
                &  [0.039]         &                  &                  &                  \\
\addlinespace
Household Treatment&                  &                  &                  &    0.016\sym{**} \\
                &                  &                  &                  &  [0.008]         \\
\midrule
Control Mean    &    0.347         &    0.101         &    0.360         &    0.012         \\
P-Value         &    0.650         &    0.650         &    0.629         &                  \\
Baseline Intercropping&        Y         &        Y         &        Y         &        Y         \\
Clustered at Village-Level&        Y         &        Y         &        Y         &        N         \\
R-Squared       &     .119         &     .119         &     .136         &      .05         \\
Observations    &      982         &      982         &      815         &      689         \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in brackets}\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \footnotesize{Note: Standard errors clustered at the village level (reported in brackets).}}\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \footnotesize{\phantom{Note: }Column (1)-(3) outcome is intercropping on any farm}\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \footnotesize{\phantom{Note: }Column (4) outcome is intercropping on NERICA farm}\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \footnotesize{\phantom{Note: }Upland (HH Level) and District*Upland (Village level) fixed effects included.}}\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \footnotesize{\phantom{Note: }This sample excludes the ROK treatment group}}\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.10\), \sym{**} \(p<0.05\), \sym{***} \(p<0.01\)}\\
\end{tabular}
}
```

This was generated using Stata.

Code that loops this table in to Tex:

```
\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
\large{Table1. Cassava} \\
\bigskip
\small{\input{table_ic_cassava.tex}}
\end{center}
```

Any help on where i can spot the error would be great! Thanks.

Comment: To the anonymous downvoter: downvoting without a comment explaining what's wrong is not really useful. Even if you think the reason is obvious...

Comment: Many multicolumn lines are missing a closing brace (i.e., `}`).  Look especially to those that have `\phantom{Note: }` in them.  Hopefully you use an editor that can easily check for balanced braces, brackets, and parentheses....

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `\footnotesize \footnotesize` is the same as `\footnotesize`

Answer (score 1):

Would this be what you seek? After my debugging, it seems that at the end of lines 34 and 35, both have a missing }.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
    {
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}

\begin{tabular}{l*{4}{c}}
\toprule
                &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(1)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(2)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(3)}         &\multicolumn{1}{c}{(4)}         \\
\midrule
tt\_tn           &   -0.043         &   -0.044         &   -0.042         &                  \\
                &  [0.051]         &  [0.046]         &  [0.049]         &                  \\
\addlinespace
tt\_ntn          &   -0.015         &   -0.016         &   -0.010         &                  \\
                &  [0.051]         &  [0.048]         &  [0.050]         &                  \\
\addlinespace
sp              &    0.002         &                  &                  &                  \\
                &  [0.039]         &                  &                  &                  \\
\addlinespace
Household Treatment&                  &                  &                  &    0.016\sym{**} \\
                &                  &                  &                  &  [0.008]         \\
\midrule
Control Mean    &    0.347         &    0.101         &    0.360         &    0.012         \\
P-Value         &    0.650         &    0.650         &    0.629         &                  \\
Baseline Intercropping&        Y         &        Y         &        Y         &        Y         \\
Clustered at Village-Level&        Y         &        Y         &        Y         &        N         \\
R-Squared       &     .119         &     .119         &     .136         &      .05         \\
Observations    &      982         &      982         &      815         &      689         \\
\bottomrule
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize Standard errors in brackets}\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize{Note: Standard errors clustered at the village level (reported in brackets).}}\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize{\phantom{Note: }Column (1)-(3) outcome is intercropping on any farm}}\\ %< ---
\multicolumn{5}{l}{ \footnotesize{\phantom{Note: }Column (4) outcome is intercropping on NERICA farm}}\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{ \footnotesize{\phantom{Note: }Upland (HH Level) and District*Upland (Village level) fixed effects included.}}\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize{\phantom{Note: }This sample excludes the ROK treatment group}}\\
\multicolumn{5}{l}{\footnotesize \sym{*} \(p<0.10\), \sym{**} \(p<0.05\), \sym{***} \(p<0.01\)}\\
\end{tabular}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: the value in the line "household treatment" would look nicer centered in the column; this can be done with `\rlap{\sym{**}}`.  and the negative values in other columns are shown with hyphens rather than minus signs.  everything here is centered, so using `\llap{$-$}` in those lines would align the decimal points, since the brackets in the entries in the following lines are balanced.

Comment: Thank you very much to all of you. I will keep your comments in mind for the next time.